# Hi iam new to spring and i want to make in my index page an input that can have as value the getmapping from my controller how can i do it

Tags: java, html, css, spring-boot, controller

I want to create a controller that returns random phone number an call it in index.html in springbooot. I want to display the result of my controller into a value qouate of html is it possible and how can i do this.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, Unfortunately, This question is a little bit too vague, it asks very generally for what would constitute a tutorial instead of asking a specific question. Therefore it is not suitable for stackoverflow as Stackoverflow is not a tutorial provider or a free code writing service, I recommend new users to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on asking questions that are well-suited for the site and best enable the community to provide helpful feedback. Goodluck :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.